# CSS centering: no top & left of the block seen on small window

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><style>
html, body{
    width: 99%; /* to prevent scroll bar when unnessery */
    height: 100%;
}
div#main_container{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%; margin-top: -200px;
    left: 50%;  margin-left: -400px;
    width: 800px; height: 400px;    
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style></head><body>
<div id='main_container'>
     Some content
</div>
</body></html>
```

PROBLEM: If I make window of the browser smaller then my content block, I can't seen the top and left parts of the block - scrolling bars looks like I am on max of top\left of content, but no top and right of my block is seen.

Why does it happens and how to fix it?

I tested in 3 browsers, so it's not browser issue.

Comment: You sure it's not the LEFT? you always have a `-400px` left margin so if it gets too short, it'll be cut off.

Comment: Yah, LEFT, I fixed this misprint in unswer. But, how can I fix this issue? I need centered block with correct scrollings on small windows to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because it's meant to happen. Let's to the math for a browser with it's height at 200px.

So, what's 50% of 200px? *datarara*.. it's 100px. That puts the top of `#main_container` at 100px in the y-axis. Give it a margin of -200px, and it goes up 200px. If it's at 100px and it moves up 200px, `#main_container`'s top gets placed at -100px. No wonder why part of it is hidden.

**The Solution**

A solution would be to make the `position: absolute` on `#main_container` relative to the `body` element and not the browser window (that is: set `position:relative` on `body`). Then, by setting a `min-height` and `min-width` on `body` equal to `#main_container`'s `height` and `width` (respectively), no matter how short the window would become, the body's dimensions would never be smaller than `#main_container` - no possible "overflow".

Applying those styles to the `body` element, however, assumes you'll only have on of those absolutely positioned boxes on your page. If this is not the case, then wrapping `#main_container` with it's own `div` would probably be the most compatible solution. Here's that solution:

**The HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    min-width: 800px; min-height: 400px;
}

.box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; margin-top: -200px;
    left: 50%;  margin-left: -400px;
    width: 800px; height: 400px;    
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```